# How to download attachment from email link

Tags: c#, email, hyperlink, download, zip

I am sending an email with a link that a customer will click and the zip file will get downloaded. but the issue now is that, when I click the link, nothing happens or the zip file doesn't get downloaded. I have searched around but I didn't get what am looking for.

The zip file does exist in the file server \127.0.0.1\Folder1...

How can I download a zip file from a link?

This is my code

```
    public void SendingEmail(string emailTo, string subject, string body, string ZipeFileName = null)
    {
        string emailHost = "myhost";
        string fromEmail = "myemail@domain";
        emailTo = "test@gmail.com";

        try
        {
            WebClient myClient = new WebClient();

            ZipeFileName = "ApplicationDocuments.zip";
            var filePath = @"\\127.0.0.1\Folder1\" + ZipeFileName + "";
            var newFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            var DownLoadlink = "<a download  href='" + filePath + "'>Click me to DownLoad<\a>";

            myClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filePath), newFileName);
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(emailHost, 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, emailTo)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = "Thank for downloading your file. To download, please  " + DownLoadlink + "",
            })
            {
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            #endregion
            //End

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder on localhost (127.0.0.1) is not available from outside of your computer.
Place your file on your portal or ftp site and add the proper address with http(s) or (s)ftp protocol.
Alternatively you can use a shared folder on your computer but this must be accessible from the internet (or where your customers are) what is not recommended.